# How to format the string in vb?

Tags: vb.net, plsql

Stated below is a string from which I want to remove the `'` and want to pass the formatted string in the PLSQL parameter. Can anyone help me out in this?

The string is:

```
'BKGSSS220005823','BKGSSS220005824','BKGSSS220005786','BKGSSS220005756','BKGSSS220005858','BKGSSS220005843','BKGSSS220005845','BKGSSS220005862','BKGSSS220005777','BKGSSS220005861','BKGSSS220005867','BKGSSS220005825','BKGSSS220005863','BKGSSS220005859','BKGSSS220005878','BKGSSS220005755','BKGSSS220005877','BKGSSS220005827','BKGSSS220005879','BKGSSS220005852','BKGSSS220005831'
```

Comment: I want the final string to be somewhat like this: 'BKGSSS220005823,BKGSSS220005824,BKGSSS220005786,BKGSSS220005756,BKGSSS220005858'

Comment: Have you tried to solve this? What is the problem you are facing? I would suggest just replacing string "','" with string ",".

Comment: If you are using comma-separated values in a database, you are doing it wrong and the [database needs normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: How to replace the string "',"?

Comment: [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, don't understand why this was hard.

```
    Dim someString As String
    someString = "'BKGSSS220005823','BKGSSS220005824','BKGSSS220005786','BKGSSS220005756','BKGSSS220005858','BKGSSS220005843','BKGSSS220005845','BKGSSS220005862','BKGSSS220005777','BKGSSS220005861','BKGSSS220005867','BKGSSS220005825','BKGSSS220005863','BKGSSS220005859','BKGSSS220005878','BKGSSS220005755','BKGSSS220005877','BKGSSS220005827','BKGSSS220005879','BKGSSS220005852','BKGSSS220005831'"
    someString = someString.Replace("','", ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sampleString As String = "'BKGSSS220005823','BKGSSS220005824','BKGSSS220005786','BKGSSS220005756','BKGSSS220005858','BKGSSS220005843','BKGSSS220005845','BKGSSS220005862','BKGSSS220005777','BKGSSS220005861','BKGSSS220005867','BKGSSS220005825','BKGSSS220005863','BKGSSS220005859','BKGSSS220005878','BKGSSS220005755','BKGSSS220005877','BKGSSS220005827','BKGSSS220005879','BKGSSS220005852','BKGSSS220005831'"
Console.WriteLine("'" & sampleString.Replace("'","") & "'")
```

Try it here [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)